# Symfony var_dump to array

Tags: php, symfony, var-dump

Symfony var_dumper is great allow show large object,
I need save this object to log - but var_dumper generate somethink like that :

```
<script> Sfdump = window.Sfdump || (function (doc) { var refStyle = doc.createElement('style'), rxEsc = /([.*+?^${}()|\[\]\/\\])/g, idRx = /\bsf-dump-\d+-ref[01 ▶
      #<span class=sf-dump-protected title="Protected property">id</span>: <span class=sf-dump-num>1</span>


      #<span class=sf-dump-protected title="Protected property">username</span>: "<span class=sf-dump-str title="15 characters"> ....
```

is possible to get result as array ?
or other way to secure (memory , invinte loop) cast object to array  ?

from doc i do this :

```
 #[Route('/', name: 'homepage')]
    public function indexAction(Request $request){

        $var = $request;

        $varCloner = new VarCloner();

        $dumper = new CliDumper(null, null, AbstractDumper::DUMP_STRING_LENGTH);

        $out = $dumper->dump($varCloner->cloneVar($var), true) ;

        dump($out);
```

here have string
but i want mulidimension array , possible ?

I need send debung as json - now have tons of html

Comment: Did you read this https://symfony.com/doc/current/components/var_dumper.html

Comment: Yes i read, i update example